# Python form dict names dynamically from List Elements

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of n values like:

```
list1=['A','B','C']
```

I want to form a dictionary from these values (inside loop) and then, assign KVPs to each dictionary.

Example:

```
for i in list1:
    value of i = dict()     # A, B , C will become dict in loop
    i[key] = value          # ,ie, A[key] = value ; & so on, for B , C dicts

print A # prints dict A ......similar, B and C dicts..
```

Note - The dict will be defined inside loop, but I would like to retain dict and its KVPs outside loop as well. Also, dict name (and not dict KVPs), will be formed dynamically from list values.

Comment: what are the *KVP*s?..

Comment: KVPs are components in an environment and their versions
my question is mainly about -
1. form dict name dynamically same as list elements
2. retain the dict and its elements (formed insied loop), even outside loop for further use

Comment: Why can't you use nested dict?

Comment: how can i form name of dict from variable value...this is my primary question ?

Comment: Before telling you that its possible (which it is), you need to realise that you're essentially asking to  create variable names dynamically. That is not recommended for good reason. A "MUCH" safer and sensible alternative is to use the variable values as "key names" in a single "big_dict" that is defined beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is create dynamically named variables: you want a variable `A` because you have the value `"A"` in a list.

The way to do this in Python is to use a `dict`. So instead of doing `A = dict()` (which is what your code is trying to do), do this instead:

```
for i in list1:
    mydictofdicts[i] = dict()     # mydictofdicts["A"] (etc) will become dict in loop
    mydictofdicts[i][key] = value
```